# iptables - Redirect local and transient outbound traffic destined for port 80 to port 8080

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, iptables

I'm having an issue with iptables due to my very small amounts of involvement with it.

I have a TOR exit relay setup and I'm trying to redirect all local and TOR traffic so that it exits my box on port 8080.

Currently I have it set as:

`-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080`

But this only seems to redirect transient traffic when I'm acting as a router rather than traffic originating from the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not commenting on TOR as I don't have much knowledge.

But for the iptables goal, here it is. `PREROUTING` involves routing. When initiating a connection from the *local* system, you're not routing. You just have to use `OUTPUT` instead/in addition of `PREROUTING`.

Scope of [`REDIRECT`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#REDIRECT):

> REDIRECT
>   This target is only valid in the nat table, in the
>   PREROUTING and OUTPUT chains, and user-defined chains which are only
>   called from those chains. It redirects the packet to the machine
>   itself by changing the destination IP to the primary address of the
>   incoming interface (locally-generated packets are mapped to the
>   localhost address, 127.0.0.1 for IPv4 and ::1 for IPv6).

So:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

EDIT:

To avoid a specific user or group to be redirected (eg to avoid an infinite loop with the service on port 8080), you can do like this (example for a service running with effective group `tor`) instead of above:

```
iptables -t nat -N OUTPUT intercept
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j intercept
iptables -t nat -A intercept -m owner --gid-owner tor -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A intercept -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Comment: I've tried this however this causes an infinite loop and then the box runs out of sockets.

Comment: I updated my answer